# How to efficiently average multiple rotations (quaternions)?

Tags: c++, quaternion, blending

So, I'm working on an animation system in C++, and am trying to blend multiple animations together. A slerp is easy on two quaternions, but is it efficient (or accurate) to chain together for more than two quaternions? I would think there'd be a better way.

I did stumble upon [this thread outlining an approach in Unity,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374087/average-of-multiple-quaternions)  but it looks pretty cumbersome, and a lot of it doesn't translate easily into the code base I'm working with.  I have actually implemented the eigenvalue-based approach, but it is very slow. There must be a more efficient way!

Comment: What are your specific needs? If you don't need the perfectly uniform distribution of slerp, a simple weighted average and renormalization does decently well for many use cases.

Comment: [See also this past Q&A on the topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/119688/39518)

Comment: @DMGregory Oh, thanks for that thread! I might have to adapt the approach to weigh each quaternion properly, but it should do the trick.